Help interpret these P-values
What does it mean when the model P-value comes out larger than alpha but the P-value for one of the main effects comes out smaller than alpha? The actual ANOVA is below. Alpha is 0,0027.


Why is alpha 0.0027? Usual choices are 0.05 and 0.01.  That doesn't mean your choice is wrong, but it seems odd without justification.

@PeterFlom It is probably designed to be equivalent to a normal distribution with two-sided critical region beyond  $\pm 3 \sigma$

Understanding "model P-value" to refer to the overall F-test (evidently with P = 0.004 here), I have closed your question as a duplicate.  But if my understanding is incorrect, please provide more information about your situation.

It means that the evidence in the data against the null hypothesis for the model is slightly weaker than the experiment was designed to detect with whatever power you chose to go with the $\alpha$=0.0027. Weaker, but not by much. The non-linear relationship between p-value and 'strength' is approximately logarithmic and so 0.0027 and 0.004 are quite similar. See section 2.4 of this A reckless Guide to p-Values
The unasked question of what to 'do' with such a result is quite hard to answer without going into the philosophy of statistical tests and scientific knowledge acquisition. The whole of the linked chapter might be a primer on those topics, but there probably is no straightforward answer. Any sensible attempt would need you to say a lot more about the experimental design and inferential objectives.
